# How do we detect issues with installs of our chrome extension?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, chrome-web-store

We run a fairly popular chrome extension with 200K+ installs and 70-90K active users (according to chrome webstore reports)

We have noticed that our numbers have started dipping in the past two months, despite a steady stream of hundreds of new daily installs. These numbers are different but broadly correlate with our Google Analytics numbers.

We suspect that some fraction of our installs are not being working, either because of some browser version-specific bugs or because it is being blocked by an anti-virus.

How do we know for sure? There doesn't seem to be some easy error reporting that we can rely on and the only other option seems to involve trying different versions and anti-viruses to see if this is true.  Is there a better method?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Provide an after-uninstall form (using [chrome.runtime.setUninstallURL](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/runtime#method-setUninstallURL) - since Chrome 41) where a user can select the reason for uninstalling. Some extensions (ZenMate, for example) do it.

Comment: Thanks. We are not trying to ascertain reasons for uninstall the extension. We want to discover bugs and reasons for the extension not working in the first place. True, people might want to uninstall the extension when they see it doesn't work, and it might help with that subset of users...

Comment: It can help if you list the possible reasons so that a user can simply click a checkbox after uninstalling. I'm assuming that the majority of users will uninstall the extension immediately after seeing it doesn't work.

Comment: Our user-base is not very tech savvy and from what we understand, they don't understand how to uninstall extensions (based on support questions and posts online). That said, I agree that it would still give us some idea.

Comment: Well, maybe you can incorporate this list of common problems into the extension itself under a prominently styled big button which will send the answer to your server.